# Using paste0 in R as a concatenation of two columns is there a way to immediately rename the column similar to the AS function in SQL

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

columns look like this

```
 col1|col2|col3|col4|
```

When i want to create a new column

```
TEST <- df %>%
group_by(col1,paste0(col3,col4))
```

I get

```
 col1|col2|col3|col4|paste0(col4,col4)
```

is there a way i can rename it and get it be

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|AnyNameIWant
```

Comment: Yes perfect, this is exactly it.

Comment: I moved it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST <- df %>% group_by(col1,AnyNameIWant = paste0(col3,col4))
```

might be what you're looking for.